# Output line by line

Tags: python, gspread

I've been researching my question, but I have not found it. So I decided to write.

In my script, after manipulating some data, I get the correct values ​​in their proper cells (A full column. Eg I need to export all values of column F).

The code I use to do this:

```
lis = wks.col_values ​​('91') # 91 are the column values
output = open ('AAA.xml', 'w')
saida.write (' ' + str (lis))
```

WHAT I NEED: I need the data in the XML file to be exported line by line.

Example:

```
/> <MilitaryServiceDetails
> <MilitaryServiceDetail
/> <MilitaryServiceDetail
/> <MilitaryServiceDetail
```

etc.

PROBLEM: the current way, the XML file has to output all the results of the COLUMN on a single line.

Example:

```
/> <MilitaryServiceDetails,> <MilitaryServiceDetail, /> <MilitaryServiceDetail, /> <MilitaryServiceDetail
```

WHAT I TRIED:

I tried using, first

```
* lis, sep = "\ n"
```

Second

```
saida.write('{}\n'.format(str(lis)))
```

I tried some solutions mentioned in this site:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-lists-in-python-4-different-ways/
And others, too.

If anyone can help, I really appreciate it.
Thank you

Comment: Depending on what module you use to work with XML, consider using [lxml](https://lxml.de/) and in particular the `pretty_print` parameter for its [`tostring()`](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#serialisation) serialization function. Considering you work with spreadsheets, do you convert your data from CSV to XML yourself?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I didn't convert the data from CSV to XML. I'm using the gsread library to manipulate data in Google Sheet. On that spreadsheet, I just select a column and export to XML. I prepared the XML structure on the spreadsheet, its ready to export.

The only problem is to get the output line by line.

Thanks again.